# How to remove the InkStroke when using the ActiveCustomDrying in uwp?

Tags: uwp, inkcanvas

I used the `ActiveCustomDrying` to customize the ink, now I want to remove them `InkStrokes`. `StrokeContainer` is `null` because of active the `CustomDrying`, so I am unable to remove the `InkStrokes` by using the `DeleteSelected` method. Can anyone suggest me how to remove the `InkStrokes` when using the `CustomDrying`.

Answer (score 0):

During the custom drying, you will store the strokes in a custom `List<InkStrokeContainer>` collection:

```
private void InkPresenter_StrokesCollected(InkPresenter sender, InkStrokesCollectedEventArgs args)
{
    var strokes = _inkSynchronizer.BeginDry();

    var container = new InkStrokeContainer(); 
    container.AddStrokes(from item in strokes
        select item.Clone()); 
    _strokes.Add(container);

    _inkSynchronizer.EndDry();
}
```

Now you can manipulate the `InkStrokeContainer` instances manually (including calls to `DeleteSelected`).

The [documentation also states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/pen-and-stylus-interactions#custom-ink-rendering) that when using `ActiveCustomDrying`, erasing with `InkToolbar` does not work automatically and you need to handle the pointer events manually

> If your app overrides the default ink rendering behavior of the InkPresenter with a custom drying implementation, the rendered ink strokes are no longer available to the InkToolbar and the built-in erase commands of the InkToolbar do not work as expected. To provide erase functionality, you must handle all pointer events, perform hit-testing on each stroke, and override the built-in "Erase all ink" command.

If you want to implement the commands, you will need to observe the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events of the toolbar buttons and then handle the pointer events yourself. A complete tutorial how to do this is [available on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/synergist/2016/08/26/using-the-inktoolbar-with-custom-dry-ink-in-windows-anniversary-edition/).

Comment: Yearly unclosed answer review - @Santhiya, if this heped, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is closed.