# InkCanvas not working on touch.?

Tags: uwp, inkcanvas

This is my code. Path drawing on the mouse, but it not drawing on touch for the first time and then draw the path. A path is not drawn on the first touch.

Xaml

```
<Grid PointerMoved="Grid_PointerMoved"
      PointerPressed="Grid_PointerPressed">

    <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" ManipulationMode="System" />

</Grid>
```

C#

// InputDevice type as None

```
      private void InkPresenter_StrokesCollected(Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkPresenter sender, 
        Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkStrokesCollectedEventArgs args)
    {
        inkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = 
             Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.None;

    }


    private void Grid_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        inkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = 
                 Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse |
                        Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;
    }


   private void Grid_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        inkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = 
         Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse |
            Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are resetting the `InputDeviceTypes` to `None` after the drawing is complete, so on first touch the `InkPresenter` is instructed not to draw.

I see no reason to change the `InputDeviceTypes` when they are reactivated each time you press on the `InkCanvas` anyway. So you can just set the `InputDeviceTypes` to `Mouse` and `Touch` in the constructor and just remove all three event handlers.

Comment: Thanks.. But this is my requirement.  I want to disable the drawing on stroke collected and enable on pointer moved. Is there any other way?

Comment: Oh, It seems I don't understand the requirement... Could you please describe what is the behavior difference between what you want and my suggestion?

Comment: I want to get the fingers count, if the finger count is 2 enable the zooming, otherwise disable the zooming(this is my actual requirement). I can't take the finger count on InkCanvas because of the InkPresenter.  So I  tried the CustomDrying , but it did not help because it returns the StrokeContainer value is null, so am not able to do Undo and Redo.   So I tried this way, it is working on the mouse. The problem only with touch.  I need finger count in InkCanvas and also I want stroke container.

Comment: I have written an answer on custom drying here in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436425/how-to-remove-the-inkstroke-when-using-the-activecustomdrying-in-uwp/48438729#48438729 , maybe it might help. But I will try to think about a solution for this in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It is useful to detect the fingers count, but I am confused how to do Undo and Redo operations. I dropped the custom drying because of the Undo and Redo operations.

Comment: Any idea about this.